# Passing structure array to DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a VB.Net Windows application which has a structure declared. I have written code in a .Net DLL which has to use that structure. However if I pass an object of that structure to the DLL it gives the error that this structure is not derived from that. How can I solve this problem ?

```
Structure ABC
    Dim A as string
    Dim B as string
End Structure
```

If I declare the same structure in the DLL, it still does not work because it's not derived from the one in Win Form Application.

The error is:

> Value of type '1-dimensional array of WindowsApplication1.Form1.ABC' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of AppDLL.Class1.ABC' because 'WindowsApplication1.Form1.ABC' is not derived from 'AppDLL.Class1.ABC'

Comment: The only reasonable solutions are to declare the structure in either a shared DLL between the DLL that needs to use it and the WinForms app, or to declare the structure inside of the DLL that needs to use it (in which case the WinForms app will also be able to use it).

Comment: You will have to declare it Public.  And declare it in the class library project so both projects can use it.